iSH on iPad stops with a hollow rectangle cursor
Using iSH on the IPad Pro M2 is fun, until the cursor turns to a hollow rectangle and I cannot type anything. The iSH simple controls disappear too. Something to do with my thumb touching the trackpad? I’m using the iPad keyboard and mouse too. I’ve managed to get out of this mode a couple of times, but not sure how.
I’m clearly missing a very simple solution.
Advice please?
The only solution that works now is to shutdown iSH and restart it.
